# Why $\mathbb{Z}_{\lambda(n)}^* \le \mathbb{Z}_{\phi(n)}^*$ does not hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

Let $\lambda(n) = \lambda(\mathbb{Z}_n^*)$ be the Carmichael function and $\phi(n) = | \mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*} |$ be the Euler function. I need to show:

$$\mathbb{Z}_{\lambda(n)}^* \le \mathbb{Z}_{\phi(n)}^*$$

But why should $\mathbb{Z}_{\lambda(n)}^* \le \mathbb{Z}_{\phi(n)}^*$ one be a subgroup of the other? This was stated in one course on cryptography but I cannot find a good justification for it.

**The claim was wrong**

In general this only holds for the subset relation. Still it would be great to find a counterexample. In return, I leave here an argument why the subset relation holds.

[image]

Comment: If $G$ is abelian then $f_k(x) = x^k$ is an homomorphism $G \to G$. If $G = (\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})^\times$ with $n$ odd (having $\phi(n) =\prod_{p^r \| n} (p-1)p^{r-1}$ elements) then $\ker(f_k)$ has $\prod_{p^r \| n} \frac{(p-1)p^{r-1}}{gcd((p-1)p^{r-1},k)}$ elements.
$\lambda(n)$ is the exponent of $(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})^\times$ ie. the least integer such that $\ker(f_k) = (\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})^\times$ ie. $\lambda(n) = lcm( ((p-1)p^{r-1})_{p^r \|n})$.

Comment: We rather have an embedding from the cyclic group $\Bbb Z_{\lambda(n)}$ (of additive notation) to the multiplicative group $\Bbb Z_{\mathbb n}^*$ of the ring $\Bbb Z_n$ which has $\varphi(n)$ elements.

Comment: I am confused because you introduced a group $G$, but the question that you ask does not appear to involve $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, I reformulated my question. $G$ is not relevant for the question itself

Comment: @Berci yes, you're right that is what follows from the facts i listed , my interest is to prove the other fact though

Comment: sorry @reuns, your comment is intended to be a proof of $\mathbb{Z}_{\lambda(n)}^* \le \mathbb{Z}_{\phi(n)}^*$?, I get the impression that you're referring to the properties I listed